# Do people perceive opacity of a color linearly?

Tags: perception, color

I am trying to create a visualization for some numbers, each ranging from 0 to 1. I was thinking of representing each number by a color (say red) of a certain opacity corresponding to its value. For example, $x_1=0.3$ would be red with an opacity of 30%, $x_2=0.6$ would be red with an opacity of 60%, etc.

My question is: Is this linear mapping the most accurate in terms of how people sense opacity? That is, does $x_1$ look like its "half" as much as $x_2$? Or do people perceive opacity like they perceive sound -- I know that sound is perceived logarithmically (see the decibel scale).